# Скрыть нули из sprintf

Tags: php

С бд получаю разные числа, например число 1 будет `10150.20000` и число 2 будет `0.00002312`. Чтобы убрать нули я использовать `round($number, 2)`, но в таком случае второе число выводиться как `0.00`, поэтому попробовать выводить так `sprintf("%.8f", $number)`, но в таком случае первое число выводиться со всеми нулями после запятой. Вопрос: как вывести числа так, что бы в первом числе, нули убирались и было только `10150.2`, и в то же время второе число выводилось целиком `0.00002312`?

Comment: `echo (float) sprintf("%.8f", $number);`..........

Comment: Также есть number_format - вместо sprint например

Comment: @АлексейШиманский попробовал float, но теперь дробное выводиться в таком виде 6.86E-6, a number_format почему то 0 возвращает

Answer (score 0):

Если всё это строки (что по мне, так странно, но исходя из условия по-другому и не может быть), то достаточно удалять нули у строки.

```
$number = '10150.20000';
echo rtrim($number, "0");

echo "\n";

$number = '0.00002312';
echo rtrim($number, "0");

// Output
10150.2
0.00002312
```

Другой вариант, но схожий

```
function specialFormat($number,  $decimals = 8) {
    return rtrim(rtrim(number_format($number, $decimals, '.', ''), '0'), '.');
}

$number = '10150.20000';
echo specialFormat($number);

echo "\n";

$number = '0.00002312';
echo specialFormat($number);

// Output
10150.2
0.00002312
```